# Drones with attachments for cleaning windows

Tags: hardware, recommendations, building, diy

Newbie on drones.

Are any attachments that can added to the bottom of a drone to carry a 1/4 or 3/8 water pipes?

Thanks,

Comment: Welcome to Drones SE! If you haven't already, please visit our [tour.](https://drones.stackexchange.com/tour) As your question stands, it looks like you're asking purely for others' personal experience. Due to the nature of this Q&A site, questions need to be answerable, as it's not a discussion forum. Please consider [editing](https://drones.stackexchange.com/posts/1920/edit) to improve your post.

Comment: Or, we have a [chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106718/droning-on) designated for discussion if you are just looking for people's experiences on this matter.

Comment: Thank your for the feedback. I will do so later in the day.